# Snackbar does not show text

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I'm using Google Design library (23.1.0) to show snackbars. My snackbar code lookls like:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getView(), "Deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent_color));
snackbar.setAction(R.string.undo, //anonymous class omitted);
snackbar.setCallback(//anonymous class omitted);
snackbar.show();
```

The snackbar is being created and shown. Action label, action color, and all listeners works as expected. The only thing is that the message "Deleted" is not being shown. If I use debugger and stop execution on: snackbar.show(), I can see that inside snackbar > mView > mMessageView there is a field called mText and it has value of "Deleted". Yet I cannot see the message on the snackbar. I have tried already using both string consts and resources id.

Whats more, I have tried using very similar code in clean project and it works. What might be the cause?

[image: Missing text]

Comment: what is `getView()` in first line.

Comment: its getView() function from Fragment,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, it looks like the text color was really the same as background. I've replaced:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getView(), "Deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
```

With:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(fab, Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#ffffff\">Deleted</font>"), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
```

And now I can see the text.

**Update:**

After a little futher investigation the default color for snackbar text is taken from theme.xml. I case of our project the value of textColor was set to #313131 and the background of snackbar is #323232. Impossible to notice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something is wrong with the color of text (R.color.accent_color). Maybe text color as background color?

Try without this option:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getView(), "Deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.setAction(R.string.undo, //anonymous class omitted);
snackbar.setCallback(//anonymous class omitted);
snackbar.show();
```

Comment: R.color.accent_color is set on action label and its blue.

Comment: Yup, the text is the same color as backgroud. Thanks. But changing it is more tricky.