# Snackbar not showing action text

Tags: android, android-studio, android-snackbar

How do I get the Snackbar to show the "UNDO" or "RETRY" text on the right hand side?

I've tried `setActionTextColor()` but it has no effect.

**MyFragment.java**

```java
Snackbar.make(getView(), "Profile saved!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    .setAction(R.string.snackbar_action_undo, null)
    .setActionTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.ColorBrightAccent))
    .show();
```

I've also tried

```java
Snackbar.make(getView(), "Profile saved!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    .setAction(R.string.snackbar_action_undo, null)
    .setActionTextColor(Color.YELLOW)
    .show();
```

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="snackbar_action_undo">UNDO</string>
```

There is no "UNDO" beside "Profile saved!".
[image: I can't see the "UNDO" text]

I've looked at the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33498628/snackbar-does-not-show-text), but it seems to apply to the text on the left-hand side.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe try to add a action with a OnClickListener

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v, "Profile saved!", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Log.e("TAG", "Done");
                        }
                    }).show();
```

Comment: how to show double action? for example "OK" and "Cancel" at once.